# How to bind datasource to Report Viewer Table

Tags: reportviewer

How to bind data source to Report Viewer.
I am using report viewer and at run time it is showing error?? 
might be I am missing some where??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragged a Table into your rdlc View, and assigned a datasource to the table.
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Adding what user1295516 has suggested, in Report Data view window, you would see the available fields under DataSet that can be used in the Report. You can drag and drop each field on to the table and change the captions if you need. This should work.

Also, can you specify what error you are getting?